# Rails select query strange behaviour

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Server with has_many :domains. I want to order my results by domains count and i don't want to use cache_count for this. So i do smth like

```
@servers = @servers.joins(:domains).select('servers.*, COUNT(domains.id) AS domains_count').group('servers.id').reorder('domains_count ASC'))
```

I have an error `no such column: domains_count`. So i check the SQL in the log and become really surprised

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, servers.id AS servers_id FROM "servers" INNER JOIN "domains" ON "domains"."server_id" = "servers"."id" GROUP BY servers.id  ORDER BY domains_count ASC
```

Why does it make this? What should i do to make my query work?

Thanks.

UPD: I was wrong a little. This strange `count_all` is produced on `@servers.size` (still WHY?). However still i have

```
SELECT  servers.*, COUNT(domains.id) AS domains_count FROM "servers" INNER JOIN "domains" ON "domains"."server_id" = "servers"."id" GROUP BY servers.id  ORDER BY domains_count ASC
```

Which always produce only one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a column in `order by` which i am guessing is a calculated column `count(domains.id)`. As you can't use a `alias` previously defined, you should use the actual calculation instead.

```
SELECT COUNT(domains.id) AS domains_count, servers.id
FROM "servers" INNER JOIN "domains" 
ON "domains"."server_id" = "servers"."id" 
GROUP BY servers.id 
order by COUNT(domains.id) 
--  ORDER BY domains_count ASC --remove this or use an appropriate column,   
-- guessing the ordering should be based on count(*)
```

Comment: Ok, now i have `SELECT "servers".* FROM "servers" INNER JOIN "domains" ON "domains"."server_id" = "servers"."id" GROUP BY servers.id  ORDER BY COUNT(domains.id) ASC`, but still only one row in result.

Comment: Thanks for the clue! I had one record with 20 domains and others with no domains. So i have to use LEFT JOIN like `SELECT  "servers".* FROM "servers" LEFT JOIN "domains" ON "domains"."server_id" = "servers"."id" GROUP BY servers.id  ORDER BY COUNT(domains.id) ASC`.

Comment: also note that, you don't need a `group by` as you are not using any aggregate functions. and in that case `order by domains.id` would be sufficient.